# Matlab - signal after command completion

Tags: windows, matlab

Is there a way to set matlab to come to the foreground of the windows when the command in complete? I can see it happening by executing a dos() but I'm unaware how window management works? Maybe there is a better way? Someone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options.  Neither exactly what you are asking for.

Option 1:  Open a new figure.

```
   figure();
   imagesc(processingDoneSplashImage);
```

If you want to get fancy, put this in a script, with a timer, and flash the image between bright green, and bright red....

Option 2: My solution to your problem.  (I find popping up windows extremely annoying.)  I put this function call at the end of my long running scripts, and the computer tells me when it's done processing....

```
function [ ] = matSpeak( textToSpeak )
%matSpeak takes some text, and outputs onto the speaker the text,
% using the .Net SpeechSynthesizer.
%  This only works on Windoze. 

if ~exist('textToSpeak','var')
    textToSpeak = 'Your processing has completed.';
end

NET.addAssembly('System.Speech');
speak = System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer;
speak.Volume = 100;
speak.Speak(textToSpeak);

end
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of audible gongs but the problem is I need visual cues. Lab systems don't have a speaker and I don't to put in an earphone just to hear the signal go. But yeah this is a pretty nice solution for a different situation, I guess. +1

Comment: @SPRajagopal new approach added.

Comment: It's better if you set `textToSpeak` to 'What is thy bidding my master'.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Growl for your notification windows?

```
cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -m ' messagestr];
system(cmd);
```

Of course with Windows you need to fix the path to the `growlnotify` binary.

- Source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/259142
- A wrapper with lots of features: [Send a notification to Growl](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25425-send-a-notification-to-growl/content/growl.m) on MATLAB Exchange
- Many more examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=growl+matlab